# Scrollable Body with auto-height Header and Footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My element is simply a Header, then Body, then Footer

```
<div id="my-element">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Currently `#my-element` has been confined to have a max-height of the browser window. `#header` and `#footer` have variable heights and should never be scrollable elements. `#body` is the only element that should be scrollable, and that occurs only when the sum of all 3 heights' exceed that of `#my-element`. When that occurs, `#body` is the element that gains a scrollbar.

For some reason I suspect that there is some straightforward solution with flexbox, but I'm not familiar with that property and have not been able to find one.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using a reserved tag that can only have one perdocument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Comment: use `<main>` instead of `<body>` imho

Comment: js solution would be pretty simple in this case. css... hmmm ...

Comment: @scrappedcola: The elements I provided are just <div>s in disguise. I just thought it would be a bit clearer like this, and the place I'm using it is actually React :/

Comment: Those details should be in the question. As presented your information is inconsistent with the problem.

Comment: @scrappedcola Sorry, I've made the change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some reason I suspect that there is some straightforward solution with flexbox

You're not wrong!

```css
/* The important bits: */
body {margin:0}
#my-element {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh
}
#header, #footer {flex-shrink: 0}
#body { overflow-y: scroll }

/* The so-you-can-see-what-it's-doing bits: */
#header,
#body,
#footer {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div id="my-element">
  <div id="header">HEADER<br>HEADER</div>
  <div id="body">
   BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>
   BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>
   BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>BODY<br>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

This is my go-to cheatsheet for flexbox; it's really quite a lot simpler than "traditional" layouts in most cases:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @user1778856, for IE, here's some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: I can't disagree even a little bit with that sentiment (and that's a good writeup of the major problem points, @Michael_B)  At this point I treat older IE as the "degrades gracefully" target, but I know that's not an option for all projects.